# Is there a way to edit/save an opening (in excel) xlsx file?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to do something like this:

```
import openpyxl as x

wb = x.load_workbook(filename)

# do some edit to the workbook

wb.save(filename)
```

The file specified by the filename is opening in Excel. Excel is locking the file so I will get permission denied error running the above code. Is there a way to edit/save it?

Comment: if have just started working on it . Have a look t xlrd. using it you can read and write into excel sheet .

Comment: Using xlrd you cannot manipulate or write to an existing xlsx file

Comment: Please explain the problem you are having. openpyxl lets you save a file with a different name than the one you opened it with. It also does not keep the file open while you are working on it.

Comment: There is an xlsx file that is opening in Excel. I want to use Python to manipulate it without having to close it in Excel. I got permission denied in the above code because the file is locked by Excel.

Comment: You can happily read a file that is open by Excel but I don't know how you expect to be able to edit it. How would you resolve both Excel and openpyxl editing the same the cell differently?

Permission denied probably means that you don't have the right file system permissions.

Answer (score -1):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
ifile = 'Whales.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(filename=ifile)

# do some edit to the workbook
wb.save(ifile)
```

Comment: Is this different from my code? I still get the permission denied error because the file is in read/write mode.

Comment: If you closely check the import statement, it is different. Also, using any library it is the foremost requirement that file should not be open while saving it using code.

Comment: Oh sorry, your import is correct as well. Just make sure to keep the file closed while saving it.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the answer is no then.

Comment: Yeah the answer is no.